# WCF service: method types changed to response/request after update

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I had an issue with updating my WCF service apparently due to [some error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344215/error-creating-wcf-webservice) that still exist in VS2022. I managed to update it thanks to the advice on the link, but it changed all my methods. Now instead of a method having 4 arguments, the method has 1 argument of type "methodRequest" which itself has the 4 values of the argument. How can I get back my old method types?

New method:[image]

Old method:[image]

Comment: Is it possible to replace the new method directly with the parameters of the old method?

Comment: @Jiayao I could try and figure that out, though I am not sure it would work, and the issue is that it is a project multiple of years old, meaning it's not just 1 method. There are 73 methods, going trough each of them to reformat them defeats the purpose of using an automated system to write them

Comment: You might look for a backup of your code in the Backlog Files folder under the Visual Studio installation path.

Comment: @Jiayao Oh, the backup is not an issue, I can easily use Git to restore it. Did it already. The issue is that I have new functions on that service that I wanna use so I need to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured a workaround for now.
Downloaded [dotnet-svcutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x) and used the proper command for it.

In my case, open the CMD in the connected services folder and use

```
dotnet-svcutil http://127.0.0.1:8080/DeliveryService/?Wsdl -d "NewDeliveryService" -n "*, DeliveryService" -syn
```

It creates a new service with everything I need, I then overwrote the old reference file manually (I am not used to CMD stuff). Important stuff: -n is the namespace you used to give it. If you had Synchronous methods, you need -sync. Hope it helps someone else.