# How to update WSDL with SVCUtil

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I have a slight issue with my WSDL service. I have a project that used to run fine, but I have to update it and the old Visual studio ways [no longer work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76579102/wcf-service-method-types-changed-to-response-request-after-update). Basically, if I try to update with a certain option I get no result, if I update without it, I don't get the right result. So I tried doing so with dotnet-svcutil but I cannot figure out how to get it to work.

I tried going to the root of the project, but it then create the reference in the root and does not use the right properties. Here are the properties of the old service

```
{
  "ExtendedData": {
    "inputs": [
      "http://127.0.0.1:8080/DeliveryService/?Wsdl"
    ],
    "collectionTypes": [
      "System.Array",
      "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2"
    ],
    "namespaceMappings": [
      "*, DeliveryService"
    ],
    "sync": true,
    "targetFramework": "netstandard2.0",
    "typeReuseMode": "All"
  }
}
```

And here is the folder structure:

[image]

Where do I need to point with my cmd and which command should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can run Svcutil.exe and specify the option to give the path to the client configuration file used in your service (which references the library). However, to load a library, Svuctil.exe must be able to locate and load the library, which means that it is either registered in the global assembly cache, registered in a path, or in the same directory as Svcutil.exe.

The easiest way is to copy the Svcutil.exe and client configuration files to the same directory as and run it from that directory.

The following document provides more help and gives examples. I think you can get more help from this.

[Custom WSDL publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-wsdl-publication)